Image of a simply connected domain under a conformal map.
Let's say D is a simply connected domain in the complex plane and f(z) is a complex-valued function of a complex variable. We have the condition on f(z) that it is everywhere differentiable on D and the derivative f'(z) is nowhere zero on D. Then what can we say about the image D' of D under f(z)?
Is it guaranteed to be simply connected as well?
I have seen two definitions of a conformal map, one as described above and another that also has a further condition of being injective. Is the image D' simply connected with the above stated conditions or do we need to further impose injectivity on f(z) for D' to be simply connected?
Does the result change if D is also known to be bounded?

Let $f(z)=z^2$ and consider $D=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|<1\}\backslash(-1,0]$. Then $D$ is bounded and simply-connected and $f'(z)=2z$ is nowhere zero on $D$, but the image $D'$ is $\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|<1\}\backslash\{0\}$, which is not simply-connected.
If $f$ is additionally injective then $f$ is a homeomorphism from $D$ to $D'$, so $D'$ must also be simply-connected. Indeed, $f$ is continuous, bijective, and an open mapping (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)).
